# I want to search div and <a> with specified class using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Hello everyone I am trying to using Beautifulsoup findall to get `<div class="div1"> content </div>` and `<a class="a1"> link </a>` at once.
I am just leaning beautifulsoup I know how this method link in `soup.find_all("div",{ "class" : "div1" }):` but how to get two different tags with specific class.

can i do something like

```
for link in soup.find_all("div",{ "class" : "div1" } and "a",{"class" : "a1"}):
```

sample Html

```
 <div class="div1"> content </div>
 <div class="div2"> content </div>
 <div class="div3"> content </div>

 <a class="a1"> link </a>
 <a class="a2"> link </a>
 <a class="a2"> link </a>
```

I searched alot but didn't find anything similar 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a [list](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) of classes to search for:

```
soup.find_all(class_=["div1", "a1"])
```

And, you can also pass a list of tags to look for:

```
soup.find_all(["a", "div"], class_=["div1", "a1"])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <div>
...     <div class="div1"> content1 </div>
...     <div class="div2"> content2 </div>
...     <div class="div3"> content3 </div>
... 
...     <a class="a1"> link1 </a>
...     <a class="a2"> link2 </a>
...     <a class="a2"> link3 </a>
... </div>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find_all(class_=["div1", "a1"])
[<div class="div1"> content1 </div>, <a class="a1"> link1 </a>]
>>>
>>> soup.find_all(["a", "div"], class_=["div1", "a1"])
[<div class="div1"> content1 </div>, <a class="a1"> link1 </a>]
```